# MVC: Should a controller access another controller's model?

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller

So I'm working on a MEAN stack where I have four models, and four controllers that handle their data.

The issue I have is that when modelA adds a new element, it needs to check for a relationship ID to modelB, and if modelB doesn't have a matching record I want to create one.

I'm just wondering what the best approach is to access modelB from controllerA.

Obviously I don't want to go through controllerB from controllerA because that just seems really messy, but I also don't want to have to include all of my models in all of my controllers because that also seems messy.

I'm new to MVC and the MEAN stack so any suggestions / thoughts / tips would be really appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by controller? Like a pre-save-method?